# React inline logic in render()

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I just wonder how apply inline templates logic in React.
I mean in case when I need change class of element how to do that easily?

```
class RegisterForm extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        let email = this.state.email.error; //true or false
        return (<div {email ? className="has-error" : className="regular"}></div>)
}
```

Then I have an error:

```
Syntax error: C:/project/components/signup/index.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (107:22)
```

How to perform that?
Or it's only possible to wrap in if/else full div block only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a couple things:

```
<div className={email ? "has-error" : "regular"}> </div>
```

Or to keep it cleaner

```
let email = this.state.email.error;
let divClass = email ? "has-error" : "regular";

return <div className={divClass}> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value conditionally not attribute. Define `className` attribute and assign its value on the basis of email value.

Write it like this:

```
<div className = { email ? "has-error" : "regular"}> </div>
```